# mysql won't save double from C#

Tags: c#, mysql, database

I have a double values in C# and I want to put them into the database.

Problem is that I have tried all the formats in the database and still I am getting a number to sign DOT.
For example if I have a number 45.548 it will be saved in database as 45
When I am debugging the code I can see that value is really sent as 45.548.

Here is my code so you can see what might went wrong:

```
MySqlConnection con = null;
MySqlCommand cmd = null;

con = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;database=Data_GPS;uid=root;pwd=******");
con.Open();
cmd = new MySqlCommand("insert into Data values (null, ?Parname , ?Parname2, ?Parname3);", con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?Parname", deciLat);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?Parname2", deciLon);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?Parname3", time);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

con.Close();
```

I have tried to change format in the database with float, double, decimal, varchar and still I am not getting the right number.

Thank you

EDIT:

This is how I fill my decimal values:

```
string[] arrLon = Lon.Split(new char[] { '°', '"' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
double dblLon = double.Parse(arrLon[0]) + double.Parse(arrLon[1], new System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo()) / 60;
double deciLon = arrLon[2] == "E" ? dblLon : -dblLon;
string[] arrLat = Lat.Split(new char[] { '°', '"' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
double dblLat = double.Parse(arrLat[0]) + double.Parse(arrLat[1], new System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo()) / 60;
double deciLat = arrLat[2] == "N" ? dblLat : -dblLat;
```

Comment: did you try something like this `cmd.Parameters.Add("@Param", MySqlDbType.Double).Value = decimalValue`

Comment: Shouldn't there be a cmd.Prepare() somewhere? Or is it not necessary?

Comment: @HaLaBi I haven't tried that. I will let you know how it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
  using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;database=Data_GPS;uid=root;pwd=******")
  {
        con.Open();
        using (MySqlCommand  cmd = new MySqlCommand("insert into Data values (null, @Parname , @Parname2, @Parname3);", con)
        {
            // change MySqlDbType.Double to reflect the real data type in the table.
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Parname", MySqlDbType.Double).Value = deciLat;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Parname2", MySqlDbType.Double).Value = deciLon;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Parname3", MySqlDbType.DateTime).Value = time;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
  }
```

always put your Connections and Commands inside `using` to make sure that you free all objects without the need of explicit `Dispose()` command.

Comment: Hi I have tried the code and it's not working. Everything is as it should be but I keep getting only values to DOT sign. What can I do? I think there is culture info problem

Comment: @denonth can I see more core? how do u put the value in the double variable.

Comment: I have edited my question, don't be confused this is gps data

Comment: when I am debugging values are sent as for example 45.548778

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I have no chance to check my idea, but this should be easily for you.  What if you add a parameter manually by creating its instance and setting its MySqlDbType property?  Then set its value:

```
MySqlParameter par = new MySqlParameter()
par.ParameterName = parameterName;
par.MySqlDbType = parameterType;
par.Value = someValue;

....
```